# Google Optimize - how experiment sessions and conversion rate are calculated?

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-optimize

I use Google Optimize with server-side A/B experiments. Server-side code targets audiences, consistently serves the appropriate variant to each user, etc. I only use the Optimize interface to create experiments, set objectives, create variants, and view reports. I configure Optimize as described in the [Server-side experiments](https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments?hl=en&technology=analyticsjs) with Universal Analytics (analytics.js) documentation.

I have performed A/A test of the Homepage with 50:50 split. The target objective is event action - click some specific button.

I run UI load tests that open the Homepage and then in 30% of cases click the desired button otherwise opens another page. In total 4000 iterations.

I expect to see calculated conversion rate 30% (this is a part of the UI load test logic) but Optimize shows conversion rate 16% (almost a half from the expected). The number of experiment sessions is much higher then 4000 (as assumed from the test), thus, the conversion rate is lower.

The question is how Google Optimize calculates experiment sessions? Why the number of sessions is higher then actual number of the experiment page views? How conversion rate is calculated?